# Why doesn't this react element render?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';


var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return React.createElement('Alert',{bsStyle: 'danger'},'this alert doesn\'t work');
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

I render this component in the dom in another component. Its works fine with a non bootstrap element like this for instance:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
const element = React.createElement(
    'h1',
    {className: 'greeting'},
    'Hello, world!'
);


var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return element;
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.createElement` in your case must accept a reference to the react component, not its name (which would never work, since it is only for built-in components).

So it should be

```
React.createElement(Alert, ...
```

References:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement